# Iterate over array or instance of java.lang.Iterable - Missing common sense solution?

Tags: java, iterator, iterable

I am trying to implement a Tree structure using a doubly linked list (called LinkedTree). With that said, when using my for-each loops, I end up getting the same repeated error: Can only iterate over an array or an instance of java.lang.Iterable. I've looked up some similar questions online but I can't seem to locate the problem. I know in order to iterator, you must have instances of iterable but isn't positions as well as children() both instances of iterable? I've included both methods with the errors, my children method, and my own implementation of iterable and iterator. Thanks in advance for the assistance.

```
public Iterator<E> iterator() {

     Iterable<Position<E>> positions = positions();
       PositionalList<E> elements = new NodePositionalList<E>();
       for (Position<E> p: positions) // ERROR @ positions
         elements.addLast(p.element());
        return elements.iterator();

}

  private void preOrderPositions(Position<E> v, PositionalList<Position<E>> pos)
          throws InvalidPositionException {
        pos.addLast(v);
        for (Position<E> w : children(v)) //ERROR @ children (v)
          preOrderPositions(w, pos);
        }
```

Children Method

```
public Iterable<Position<E>> children(Position<E> v)
        throws InvalidPositionException {
    TreePosition <E> p = checkPosition(v);

    if (isExternal(v))
        throw new InvalidPositionException("");
return p.getChildren();
```

Iterator

```
public interface Iterator<E> {

public boolean hasNext();

public E next();

public void remove();

}
```

Iterable

```
public interface Iterable <E> { 

public Iterator<E> iterator(); 

public Iterable<Position<E>> positions();

}
```

ElementIterator (my iterator implementation)

```
public class ElementIterator<E> implements Iterator <E> {

private PositionalList <E> list;
private Position <E> cursor;

public ElementIterator (PositionalList <E> L){

    list = L;
    cursor = (list.isEmpty())? null: list.first();
}

public boolean hasNext() {
    return (cursor != null);
}

public E next(){

    E toReturn = cursor.element();
    cursor = (cursor == list.last())? null: list.next(cursor);
    return toReturn;
}

public void remove(){

    throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
}



}
```

EDIT: I converted the for-each loop into a while loop as shown below....

```
protected void preOrderPositions(Position<E> v,
        PositionalList<Position<E>> pos) throws InvalidPositionException {

    pos.addLast(v);

    Iterator<Position<E>> iter = children(v).iterator();

    while (iter.hasNext()) {
        Position<E> w = iter.next();
        preOrderPositions(w, pos);

    }

}
```

Comment: If I get you right, you want to have an Interator looping over all your tree elements. If yes you have to implement either a depth first search or a breatch first search algorithm for *one* Iterator.

Answer (score 3):

You can only iterate over a class that implements `java.lang.Iterable`. You however try to iterate over your custom iterable interface. That doesnt work:

```
public interface Iterable <E> { 

    public Iterator<E> iterator(); 

    public Iterable<Position<E>> positions(); // <- your custom Iterable class is returned here, NOT java.lang.Iterable

}
```

If you want to iterate using your iterable class, extend `java.lang.Iterable`

```
 public interface Iterable <E> extends java.lang.Iterable<E>
```

> HINT: Do not write classes / interfaces that have the same name as anything in the `java.lang` package.

Comment: I understand what you are saying about extending the java.lang.Iterable but for this assignment I can't. I have to implement everything on my own. That's where I am running into my problems. As well, all the interfaces have to be the same names such as iterator, iterable, etc.

Comment: I converted the for-each loop to a while loop. The code is posted as an edit to the original question.